# bash flock an output file

Tags: bash, flock

If several processes may be writing to the same output file, is it safe to flock the output file itself instead of a separate lock file?

E.g. is this safe?

```
outputFile=output.dat
exec 200>>"$outputFile"
flock -e 200
grep -i error "$1" >> "$outputFile"
flock -u 200
```

All of the examples I've found with flock use a separate lock file.

E.g.

```
outputFile=output.dat
lockFile=/var/tmp/output.dat
exec 200>"$lockFile"
flock -e 200
grep -i error "$1" >> "$outputFile"
flock -u 200
```

Comment: I'd suggest `>&200` -- faster than `>>"$outputFile"` because you're using the handle that's already open.

Comment: (and btw, it's *not* important to quote `"error"`, but *is* important to quote `"$1"`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I've updated it for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you're proposing is safe, within the specific (narrow) usage pattern given.

#### Things You Can Safely Do With A Single File

- Open the file *for append only* without already holding the lock.
- Truncate the file *only after the lock is held*
- Modify the file while the lock is held *in a manner that doesn't change which inode the directory entry refers to*.

#### Things You Can Only Do With Two Separate Files

- Initially open the lockfile with `O_TRUNC`.
- Use the create-and-rename pattern to atomically modify the data file while the lock is held.
- Delete the data file entirely, as with `rm` -- ensuring that any newly-created version gets a different inode -- while holding the lock.